# Remove dcp from publishing package

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, componentpresentation, custom-resolver

We have a CT that has DCP's in his tbb razor code using the specific tag.

We want to remove this dcp's from the package that is generated when I publish the component related with the initial CT.

We try to build a Custom Resolver to remove this dcp's but int the `Tridion.Collections.ISet<ResolvedItem> resolvedItems` 
list we can't see this components / templates.

We found the initial CT but not the second level dcp's.

Also, we try to execute this CT in the Template Builder to see if the dcp's is added when the CT is rendered, but we can't find these dcp's in the result of the template builder.

When is added this dcp's to the final package? How can I remove it from the publication package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you publish a component dynamically, you have "Component Presentations" in the package, which are combinations of "Component + Attached Component Templates".

Assuming you want to delete component Presentations from the package. but the question is why do you want to do so? because if you don't need component presentations in the package, simply don't ADD them to the package by detaching the dynamic CTs from the Component.

If you want to remove the CPs from the Package anyways, Custom Resolver would not help you as with this you can customize the dependent resolved items of the published item. I think `Deployer/Storage extension` could be a option here for you.

Also, I would request you to explain the problem you want to solve for better answers.